# htaccess redirect going to bizarre place

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Quantum physics is trivial compared to htaccess. I'm trying to visibly redirect from one URL to another, i.e. complete with HTTP request. I have:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(inc|out\.|admin|static|channel) [NC]
#RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)(/([a-z_]+))?/?$ channel/$1/$3 [L,R=301]
```

But unfathomably, that visibly bounces the user to

```
mydomain.com/home/xxxx/public_html... //etc
```

If I remove `[L,R=301]` it does do the redirect, but only silently. What's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Quantum physics is trivial compared to htaccess

lol :)))

Use this rule with absolute target URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(inc|out\.|admin|static|channel) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)(/([a-z_]+))?/?$ /channel/$1/$3 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Chnage is to add a `/` before `channel` in target URL. Without a `RewriteBase` directive in place and missing leading `/` in target URL it adds current directory before target URL while doing a full redirect.

**PS:** However I consider this a `mod_rewrite` bug. IMO it should consider current relative path from `DocumentRoot` as default `RewriteBase`.

Comment: Yeap, that's it. Thanks. Would you mind explaining what magic you did? :)

Comment: I just added `/` before `channel` in target URL. Without a `RewriteBase` directive in place and missing leading `/` in target URL it adds current directory before target URL while doing a full redirect. (Honestly I consider it a `mod_rewrite` bug. IMO it should consider current path as `RewriteBase`)

Comment: Aha, interesting. You might want to put that info in the answer as it's an informative part of it. Thanks for the help - twice in a day :)